# Compiling a python code using brian package

Tags: python, python-3.6

I'm about to generate a simple brian code and run it on Ubuntu terminal:

```
  from brian import*
  brian_sample_run()
```

I saved it under the name `sample.py` and tried to compile it via command:`python sample.py`. But it seems that the brian commands are not recognized this way. What should I do?

The error I get is:

```
 NameError : name 'brian_sample_run' is not defined
```

p.s :
I'm using sublime editor to write brian code and compile it with python in terminal.python codes compile properly (which means that sublime supports python interpreter)but whenever I use brian libraries ,I run in to errors ,indicating that they're not recognized when written in sublime.I should also add up when I open brian in the terminal and run the codes,I get no errors,which also shows that the package has been installed correctly.

Comment: *"it seems that the brian commands are not recognized this way"* - what makes you say that? What happens?

Comment: @jonrsharpe got an error saying so

Comment: *What error?* Give a [mcve].

Comment: @jonrsharpe NameError : name 'brian_sample_run' is not defined

Comment: @Ghazal.S you should be more specific Abji

Comment: @mjsameri Abji :D what should I be more specific about?I'm using sublime editor to write brian code and compile it with python in terminal...python codes compile properly (which means that sublime supports python interpreter)but whenever I use brian libraries ,I run in to errors ,indicating that they're not recognized when written in sublime.I should also add up when I open brian in the terminal and run the codes,I get no errors,which also shows that the package has been installed correctly.

Comment: @Ghazal.S come on you just copied your question for me :D , I mean if you tell us about your code  or the way code and what you used in your code , maybe some one could help you to solve your problem ! with my little experience expert people usually don't respond to this kind of question !

Answer (score 0):

The default python interpreter of sublime doesn't support brian package.I should have used pycharm instead.